# Python Nested List Comprehension Error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert a normal nested iteration into a nest list comp and I'm having trouble.

```
for k in r.json()['app_list']:
    for i in titles:
        if k['name'] == i['name'] and k['platform'] == i['platform']:
            array.append(session.get(k['api_url'], headers=headers).json())
return array
```

Works fine, however

```
return [session.get(k['api_url'], headers=headers).json()
        for i in titles for k in r.json()
        if k['name'] == i['name'] and k['platform'] == i['platform']]
```

throws this error

```
if k['name'] == i['name'] and k['platform'] == i['platform']]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Read your `for` clauses again.

Comment: Also, your first one works just fine. Why mangle it up in to a comprehension that you can't even do in a single line?

Comment: Didn't you miss that `['app_list']` part?

Comment: List comp is more readable... for me at least

Comment: What's the difference between `r.json()` and `r.json()['app_list']`? Could you paste the output of `r.json()`?

Comment: I can't, confidential data :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your nesting order wrong and you forgot to get the `'app_list'` key from the `r.json()` dictionary.

List comprehension loops are still listed in the same order, left to right as you nest them. In other words, use the *same order* as your original nested `for` statements:

```
return [session.get(k['api_url'], headers=headers).json()
        for k in r.json()['app_list']
        for i in titles
        if k['name'] == i['name'] and k['platform'] == i['platform']]
```

The above was reached simply by putting everything in the `array.append()` call *at the front*, then removing the `:` colons from the `for` and `if` statements and putting the result inside `[...]` square brackets.

You forgot the `['app_list']` subscription to the `r.json()`, and that's the actual cause of the exception; `r.json()` produces a dictionary, so each `k` was bound to a *key* from that dictionary, making the `k['name']` subscription fail.